# Intermediate Value Proof with Cos

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=a_1+a_2\cos x$. If $|a_1|<a_2$, I need to show that $f$ has at least one real root in $[0,\pi]$.

What is significant about the "<" distinction? How would I formalize a proof from this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Graph a few examples with $a_1$ and $a_2$ both positive.  For example, start with $a_1 = a_2 = 1$.  Now raise and lower $a_1$.  Then return $a_1$ to $1$, then raise and lower $a_2$.

Comment: hmm yeah I see that when $a_1 < a_2$ the graph definitely crosses the x axis...

Comment: how can i demonstrate this phenomenon in proof though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $f(0)=a_1+a_2$ and $f(\pi)=a_1-a_2$. Hence
$$
|a_1|<a_2\quad\Rightarrow \quad a_1^2<a_2^2\quad\Rightarrow\quad f(0)f(\pi)=a_1^2-a_2^2<0.
$$
Therefore $0$ is between $f(0)$ and $f(\pi)$ (one is positive, the other is negative, and we don't care who is who given what we want to prove).

Now you can apply the intermediate value theorem on $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Compute $f(0)$ and $f(\pi)$. What does $|a_1|<a_2$ (i.e. $-a_2<a_1<a_2$) imply?

Comment: I see, so $f(0)$ is distinctly positive and $f(\pi)$ is negative, thus a real root?